# Javascript deepcopy without JSON or variable assignment

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

I have a javascript question:
I was doing some challenge exercises from a JS book I'm learning from and I have no idea how to go about it and I don't have the sample answers. The aim is to write a deep copy function using *only ES6*'s arrow functions without using any JSON methods or any variable assignments. The author also suggests no scopes using the `{}` brackets. Any hints or tips on how I can do this?

Comment: Create a recursive function which accepts a value and will return a copy of it. Check the type of the value. If it's primitive (string, number, boolean...), just return it. If it's an Array, return an new Array which maps every element to a recursive call of that function, and do the same for every property if it's an Object. If you're having trouble with ES6, do it in ES5 first until you get it working, and try "translating" it then, but that shouldn't be that difficult

Comment: I have implemented it in ES5 but the ternary was kind of hard to wrap my mind around as I wasn't sure what to do with the return values. Seen your post below too. It works as expected and I see what you did there with the nested ternarys (ternaries?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a recursive function which accepts a value and will return a copy of it. Check the type of the value. If it's an Array, return an new Array which maps every element to a recursive call of that function. If it's an Object, create a new Object with copies of its properties. If it's primitive (string, number, boolean...), just return it.

> On a side note, writing this without any variable assignment & curly brackets may be fun for learning, but it makes it a lot less readable. I would **never write it this way at  work**:

```js
const deepCopy = v =>
  // Is it an Array?
  v instanceof Array ?
    // If it is, map every value to its copy
    v.map(deepCopy) :
    // Otherwise, is it a non-null Object?
    (typeof v === "object" && v !== null) ? 
      // If it is, create a new Object with copies of its property values
      Object.entries(v)
            .reduce((acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [k]: deepCopy(v) }), {}) :
      // Otherwise, just return the value
      v;


console.log(deepCopy({foo: 'bar', arr: [{baz: 42}, true]}));
console.log(deepCopy("Hello world"));
console.log(deepCopy(["a", "b", null]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get arrays of keys and values with Object.keys() and Object.values(), then iterates and assigns those items to a new object, try this:

```js
let obj = {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'};

let keys = Object.keys(obj);
let values = Object.values(obj)

console.log(keys, values)

let newObj = {};

for( let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++ ){
    newObj[keys[i]] = values[i] 
}

console.log(newObj);

newObj.key1 = 'asd';

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: What about `let obj = { foo: { bar: 42 } }`? (the inner Object will not be a copy, it will be a reference to the original)